# How to get all vertices connected to at least two other vertices in a group using gremlin?

Tags: database, graph, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am pretty new to GraphDBs so excuse me if this is trivial.

I have two groups of vertices in an Azure CosmosDB using gremlin. Group **a** and **b**. Every vertex of **group a** can connect to any vertex of **group b**, once at most. I am looking to find every vertex in **group b** that is connected to at least two vertices in **group a**.

[image]

So in this example I would like to get back vertices `[b2, b3]`.

In case it's relevant: There would usually be a lot more vertices in **group b**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a graph from your diagram, you can do something like this

```
g.addV('person').property('group','A').property('name','a1').as('a1').
    addV('person').property('group','A').property('name','a2').as('a2').
    addV('person').property('group','A').property('name','a3').as('a3').
    addV('person').property('group','B').property('name','b1').as('b1').
    addV('person').property('group','B').property('name','b2').as('b2').
    addV('person').property('group','B').property('name','b3').as('b3').   
    addV('person').property('group','B').property('name','b4').as('b4').
    addE('knows').from('b3').to('a2').
    addE('knows').from('b3').to('a3').
    addE('knows').from('a2').to('b2').
    addE('knows').from('b2').to('a1').
    addE('knows').from('a1').to('b1').
    addE('knows').from('a3').to('b4').iterate()          

gremlin>   g.V().has('group','B').
......1>         filter(both().has('group','A').count().is(gte(2))).
......2>         values('name')  
==>b2
==>b3
```

If there is a possibility that any of the vertices may have a lot of connected edges it is probably more efficient to change the test part of the query to be.

```
filter(both().has('group','A').limit(2).count().is(2))
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great. Since Azure doesn*t support filter(), I tried this with where() instead but it does give the nodes back I am looking for.